# How can I cache DataFrame with Kryo Serializer in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, kryo

I am trying to use Spark with Kryo Serializer to store some data with less memory cost. And now I come across a trouble, I cannot save a DataFram e(whose type is Dataset[Row]) in memory with Kryo serializer. I thought all I need to do is to add `org.apache.spark.sql.Row to classesToRegister`, but error still occurs:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.kryo.classesToRegister=org.apache.spark.sql.Row --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer --conf spark.kryo.registrationRequired=true
```

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

val schema = StructType(StructField("name", StringType, true) :: StructField("id", IntegerType, false) :: Nil)
val seq = Seq(("hello", 1), ("world", 2))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)
df.count()
```

Error occurs like this:
[image]

I don't think adding `byte[][]` to `classesToRegister` is a good idea. So what should I do to store a dataframe in memory with Kryo?

Answer (score 2):

`Dataset`s don't use standard serialization methods. They use specialized columnar storage with its own compression methods so you don't need to store your Dataset with the Kryo Serializer.