# How to register StringType$ using kryo serializer in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I'm trying to use the kryo serializer in spark. I have set `spark.kryo.registrationRequired=true` to make sure that I'm registering all the necessary classes. Apart from requiring that I register my custom classes, it is asking me to register spark classes as well like `StructType`.

Although I have registered the spark `StringType`, it is now crashing saying that I need to register `StringType$` as well.

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType$
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType$.class);
Serialization trace:
dataType (org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField)
fields (org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType))
```

I am importing spark implicits in order to read in json. I'm not sure if this is contributing to the problem.

```
import spark.implicits._
val foo = spark.read.json(inPath).as[MyCaseClass]
```

I do realize that setting registration required to false will stop this error, but I am not seeing any performance gain in that case so am trying to make sure that I register every necessary class.

Comment: See comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433383/how-can-i-cache-dataframe-with-kryo-serializer-in-spark: If you're only using `DataFrame`s/`Dataset`s (and not `RDD`s) - there's no reason to use Kryo at all: Kryo is used to serialize RDD data; When using DataFrames / Datasets, Spark's Encoders (or pre-set datatypes) are used for serialization.

Comment: I am using an RDDs as well. I'd love to use Datasets exclusively but have to drop down to RDDs at one point.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, and after some experiments, I managed to solve it with the following line:

```
Class.forName("org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType$")
```

That way you register the class in Kryo and it stops complaining.

A good reference: https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201603.mbox/%3CCAHCfvsSyUpx78ZFS_A9ycxvtO1=Jp7DfCCAeJKHyHZ1sugqHEQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

Cheers